# How do I make combinations from data inside database

Tags: php, logic

I would like to know how I would be able to make combinations of all possibilities from data in my database.

Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, and Item5

There can be any amount of items, what I want to do is to show all the combinations and then to be able to manipulate them, either erase a row or make them into more combinations of 3, 4 and so on items.

ex.
Database name "store"
table name "item"

```
ItemID        Item  
1             Item1  
2             Item2
3             Item3
4             Item4
5             Item5
```

the following are an example of combination of 2 items, I would like to them make them into a 3 item combination. This is for php programming.

```
Item1,Item2  
Item1,Item3  
Item1,Item4  
Item1,Item5  
Item2,Item3  
Item2,Item4  
Item2,Item5  
Item3,Item4  
Item3,Item5  
Item4,Item5
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a SQL Cross Join. You could either set up another table that is identical or make a temp table and then cross join your two tables on the properties you wish to cross join.
`select b.item, d.item from itemtable1 b cross join (select * from itemtable2) d`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of items you have, a few nested `foreach` loops might do the trick:

```
$arrItems = array("Item1","Item2","Item3",...,"ItemN");

foreach ($arrItems as $v1) {
  foreach($arrItems as $v2) {
    echo $v1 . "," . $v2;
  }
}
```

The number of pairings you have corresponds to the number of loops you nest. Someone else might be able to offer an iterative algorithm with `n` nests, without having to hard-code the nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go for a self join

This is in T-SQL

Same should work in mysql also

```
select t1.Item+','+t2.Item from item t1 join item t2 on t1.ItemID <t2.ItemID order by t1.ItemID,t2.ItemID
```